# My old CentOS 6 computer died. How do I make a new one boot with the old HDDs?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, centos, grub

As the title says, I have had a CentOS 6 box for some years, but recently it died. Since it was quite old, I've upgraded it with a whole new box (new psu, motherboard, RAM, CPU), but kept the HDDs. My theory was that since grub existed on the hard drive, I should hopefully be able to at least boot and recover the files, then do a clean install later (it died right before my automated backup process ran).

The machine loads through the BIOS to a screen that just says "GRUB" with a blinking cursor. Is this recoverable into a bootable state, or am I going to have to just grab the files with a linux live disc and wipe the HDDs?

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. The reasons for this machine not being able to boot can be so many that giving you a good answer for this might not be possible without more information. What caused this to die in the first place? It might be as simple as setting up grub on the on the master sector manually depending on the reasons for this host to die in the first place.

Comment: It was likely the power supply, but possibly also the motherboard. I believe the HDDs are intact and functioning normally. I did a number of tests on them while it was in the process of dying.

Comment: I've edited the question to be somewhat more clear on what was replaced with the new machine; it really is an entirely new machine with just the old hard drives.

Comment: If all is well with the drives, the solution might be to just boot a live operating system like Ubuntu Live or something similar and set the grub configuration to match how the new machine perceive your hard drives and reinitialise it. In any case, I suggest you reinstall the OS since new hardware means that it probably has other functionality than the old one did not have. Also the settings chosen by the installer when installing the first time might not be compatible the new hardware. I would in such a situation reinstall from scratch.

Comment: All right, thanks for the input. It makes sense that such a re-grubbed franken-install would be unstable. I think I will be wiping it and reinstalling from scratch.